# how to show form submission values on input field after form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I want to show values on input field after submit a form. I already get it on `console` but it is not working on input field. Here is my jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('form').submit(function() {
    let first_name = jQuery('#names_first_name_').val();
    jQuery("#names_first_name_").val(first_name);

    let last_name = jQuery('#names_last_name_').val();
    jQuery("#names_last_name_").val(last_name);

    let email = jQuery('#email').val();
    jQuery("#email").val(email);

    console.log(first_name);
    console.log(email);
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? The code is just taking the value from 3 fields, and setting the values back to what they already are...? That makes no sense. Also note that you most likely need to call `preventDefault()` in the `submit` event handler to stop the form submission from redirecting away from the current page.

Comment: after submit my form i want the just submission data will be show on input field values

Comment: But... that should be happening by default. The answer you've put below is equivalent to using the setter of `val()` anyway, so absolutely none of this makes any sense.

Comment: probably after submission form it will reset form data thats why i have facing that issues. but it will fix see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed with set attribute value:

```
jQuery("#names_first_name_").attr("value", first_name);
```